# mongodb distinct values of a row in a generic fashion

Tags: mongodb, scala, salat

given the following code:

```
 def findDistinctTypeValues(): Set[String] = {
    //cast all instances from Any to String
    val coll = dao.collection.distinct("hybridType") map (_.asInstanceOf[String])
    coll.toSet
  }
```

How would one do this in a generic fashion ? (in this case i knew upfront that "hybridstype" is a string. there must be a generic approach to it i presume.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Salat author here.

Look at `SalatDAO#primitiveProjections` -

```
MyDAO.primitiveProjections[String](/* some query or DBObject.empty for all */, "hybridType")
```

See the section on projections at [SalatDAO wiki page](https://github.com/salat/salat/wiki/SalatDAO)

Comment: Is there an easy way to retrieve the Type of the corresponding fieldname? (assuming the type of that certain field is consistent amongst all documents of that collection)

Comment: As far I understand, the results of `MyDAO.primitiveProjects[String]` would not necessarily be distinct. Am I misunderstanding something?